# What exactly does the distance between two point on Möbius strip represent?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

We know that "The configuration space of $2$ not necessarily distinct points on the Jordan curve is the quotient of the 2-torus, $T^2/\Bbb Z_2$, which is the Möbius strip." I want to know

> **Question:** What exactly does the distance between two point on Möbius strip  represent(in the sence  of points on Jordan curve)?

Comment: It depends how you metrize this quotient space.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How we can encode this distance from Möbius strip?